# Float numbers are trimmed after point when using NSOperation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Ok, this is so impossible that I don't really know how to ask. I'm developing an iPhone app, and at one point I needed to use NSOperation for some background task. The problem is that even the simplest float calculation it's trimmed after the point (eg 1/2= 1.0). Initially I thought that's a concurrency problem but then I tried:

```
NSLog(@"%f", 1/2);
```

And it logged 1.00000. How is this even possible? Surely I do something wrong!

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: try - `NSLog(@"%f", (1.0/2.0));`. Even though you say - `NSLog(@"%f", (1/2));`, it should give you `0.0000` because `int/int` returns an `int` and that you are asking to print using a floating point specifier.

Comment: @Mahesh: Thats still not a division of two floats but of two doubles.

Comment: @JustSid- Correct. Forgot to append `f` to the two numbers at the end. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dividing two integers, which then rounds up to 1.
If you want to divide two floating point variables, either first save the values into a float and divide it or write `.0f` at the end of your value to tell the compiler that you are working with a float. Eg: `1.0f / 2.0f`

Just writing `1.0 / 2.0` like suggested in the comments will result in a division of two doubles, as the compiler will default the values to double.

Comment: BTW: the `float` expression is coerced to a `double` in this specific case anyway so the trailing `f` is unnecessary unless you explicitly need single precision vs. double precision.